# cannot start apache server after upgrading php to 5.5 in mac

Tags: php, macos, apache

I am going to develop laravel application but I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 with php version 5.3. So I installed and updated the php version to 5.5. And run this command without knowing why.

```
    export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

Things got worst, my apache server in my xampp application cannot start.

My questions are:

- is it okay to upgrade and update php version even though it was statically installed in every mac devices?
- http://php-osx.liip.ch/ I follow this tutorial how to upgrade php version, Am I doing it right? or was there something I'm missing?
- Lastly, is there any relation why my xampp Apache server cannot start when upgrading php version?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: that command means adding '/usr/local/php5/bin' to PATH variable. are you getting any error? look in your server's errror.log

Comment: it says,

 Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started

but the server status is stop .. weird